# Shell: how to format milliseconds properly with %N or %3N

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, datetime

I am trying to return the date with milliseconds with 3 decimal places. However, the date that prints out looks like this `2023-05-09T15:36:23.3N`. It prints the "3N" at the end instead of the milliseconds.

I am currently using this format `date +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N`. Even when I remove the 3 just to get the default amount of decimal places, it still just prints out an "N".

Comment: Which version of bash? `bash --version`

Comment: @GillesQuénot What does the bash version have to do with the `date` command? It's not a built-in.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there's a `%N` conversion in `date`?

Comment: `%N` is a GNU extension, not supported by all versions of `date`.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` >= 5:

```
$ echo ${EPOCHREALTIME}
```

```
1683669018.026445
           ^^^^^^
        microseconds
```

Or

```
now=$EPOCHREALTIME sec=${now%[,.]*} msec=${now#*[,.]}
printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.)T%.3s\n' "$sec" "$msec"
```

```
2023-05-10 00:22:59.432
                    ^^^
                milliseconds
```

With `GNU` date:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'
```

```
2023-05-09 23:04:28.423
                    ^^^
               milliseconds
```

With `Perl` (only builtins modules):

```
perl -MPOSIX -MTime::HiRes=time -e '
    my $t = time;
    printf "%s.%03d\n", 
        POSIX::strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        localtime($t)), 1000*($t - int($t)
    )
'
```

```
2023-05-09 23:04:28.423
                    ^^^
                milliseconds
```

Replace `localtime` by `gmtime` if you need GMT time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to choose how many decimal places for milliseconds with this method or no?

Comment: Also, my bash version is GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1) @Gilles Quénot

Comment: An example would be 2023-05-09 22:55:26.442 instead of 2023-05-09 22:55:26.442940

Comment: Look my `GNU date` answer, post edited

Comment: I still get this as my output: "2023-05-09 16:17:51.3N", so I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: You have a old version of `date`. What is the output of `date --version` ? Which OS?

Comment: @erosej That bash version makes me suspect you're on macOS, not Linux; if so, you should correct the tags on your question. macOS has the bsd version of `date`, not a GNU version, and it doesn't support the `%N` format specifier at all (`date` is poorly standardized in a number of ways). Also, bash's `printf` didn't support the `%(...)T` format until version 4.4, and `$EPOCHREALTIME` wasn't added until version 5.0, so you won't have those either.

Comment: But Perl 's version should work, even on *BSD

Comment: I confirm that the Perl works properly on macOS.

Comment: The idea that you could usefully obtain sub-millisecond accuracy by running an external command from the shell is deeply flawed. The execution time of the `date` utility itself will take much more time than that.

Comment: Which command seems flawed @tripleee?

Comment: The idea that you want or need millisecond accuracy from `date` is flawed. How long does the command take to start up and actually run? Should the result it produces represent the time it was started (impossible), when it finished (close, but never accurate) or some middle point in between? What possible use could you have for many decimals when the margin of error from taking the measurement is much larger than that?

Comment: If you have a fix, welcome